# Буфер обмена сдвигает активити и сбивает выделение текста

Tags: android, textview, clipboard

Проблема: при длительном нажатии на текст (textView с атрибутом android:textIsSelectable="true"), для того чтоб выделить, панель буфера обмена сдвигает активити и выделение пропадает вместе с панелью буфера обмена.
Как сделать чтобы выделение текста не пропадало?

Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    <TextView
        android:text="Пользователи, которым были подтверждены и оплачены выполнения"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView59"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:background="#65b40b"

        android:textSize="16sp"

        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/listofhistory"
        android:divider="@color/colorAccent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `панель буфера обмена сдвигает активити` -- вот это вот непонятно.

Comment: Также как экранная клавиатура может сдвигать активити, так сдвигает и панель буфера обмена (clipboard).